# How to display a MsgBox in case of error 1004?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I created this code to change pivot fields in 4 workbooks.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Account_Name()
    
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Book1.xlsm"
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Book2.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Book3.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Book4.xlsx"

    Dim workbookNames As Variant
    workbookNames = Array("Book1.xlsm", "Book2.xlsx", "Book3.xlsx", "Book4.xlsx")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(workbookNames) To UBound(workbookNames)
        
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks(workbookNames(i))
        
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Analysis")
        
        Dim rootAccount As String
        rootAccount = ws.Cells(1, 6).Value

        Dim pt As PivotTable
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            With pt
                With .PivotFields("Root Account")
                    .ClearAllFilters
                    .CurrentPage = rootAccount
                End With
            End With
        Next pt
    Next i

End Sub
```

The code works if Root Account is found in all 4 workbooks.

If Root Account is not available in any of the workbooks it gives

> Runtime Error 1004

on `.CurrentPage = rootAccount`.

Is it possible to clear the filter from Root Account and display MsgBox that this Root Account is not available?

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: ".CurrentPage = rootAccount", getting error in this line.  I want if there's an error, it should display MsgBox and clear filters from Root Account.  Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *On Error Resume Next* When Single Statement

```vb
' Declare a Long variable to hold the error number.
Dim cpErrNum As Long

With .PivotFields("Root Account")
    .ClearAllFilters
    
    ' Attempt to...
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping (ignore errors)
        .CurrentPage = rootAccount ' ... do this.
        cpErrNum = Err.Number ' store the error number in the variable
    On Error GoTo 0 ' disable error handling
    If cpErrNum <> 0 Then ' an error occurred
        MsgBox "Root Account is not available.", vbExclamation
    'Else ' no error occurred i.e. 'cpErrNum = 0'; do nothing
    End If

End With
```

- Note that objects are handled differently i.e. there is no need for the *Long* variable and you check if the object was not referenced with e.g. `If obj Is Nothing Then`.